Doubts in a proof of 2d random walks hitting 0 from far away
I am reading this paper and I want to understand how equation (2.8) on page 9 is proved. Essentially, it says that 2d random walks starting increasingly far away from the origin are unlikely to hit the origin within increasing time spans.
Let $Z_t$ be a time continuous random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ jumping at rate 2 to nearest neighbors. Let $T>0$ and $\tau_0=\inf\{t\geq 0: Z_t=0\}$ the first hitting time of $0\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\{x_\beta\in\mathbb{Z}^2: \beta>0\}$ a sequence of points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $|x_\beta|>(\sqrt{\beta}\log(\beta^{-1}))^{-1}$.
Statement (2.8): $\lim_{\beta\rightarrow 0}\mathbb{P}\left(\tau_0\leq \frac{1}{\beta}\log(\beta^{-1})T|Z_0=x_\beta\right)=0$
Supposed proof: For a discrete time 2d random walk $S_n$, they consider:

the probability that the random walk started in $x_\beta$ hits the ball of radius $2K$ before it exits the ball of radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}}\log(\beta^{-1})$.

that is
$\alpha(\beta):=\mathbb{P}(\sigma<\rho(\beta)|S_0=x_\beta)$
where
$$\sigma=\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}: |S_n|\leq 2K\},\quad\rho(\beta)=\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}: |S_n|\geq \sqrt{\beta^{-1}}\log(\beta^{-1})\}$$
They say

that $\alpha$ converges to 0 as $\beta\rightarrow 0$. This proves (2.8).

I understand why $\alpha(\beta)\rightarrow 0$, but not why this implies the statement.
Question: How does the statement follow?
Update: Here is another way to view this problem. Again I'm missing something:
We can relate $Z_t$ and $S_n$ from above as follows:
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_0\leq \beta^{-1}\log(\beta^{-1})T|Z_0=x_\beta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(\beta^{-1}\log(\beta^{-1})T)^n}{n!}e^{-\beta^{-1}\log(\beta^{-1})T}\mathbb{P}(\sigma_0\leq n|S_n=x_\beta)}$$
where $\sigma_0=\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}:S_n=0\}$ is the discrete analogue of $\tau_0$. I hoped to find a bound for $\mathbb{P}(\sigma_0\leq n|S_0=x)$ in the literature, but only encountered the asymptotic $\mathbb{P}(\sigma_0>n|S_0=0)\sim \frac{\pi}{\log(n)}$ (Spitzer, F.: Principles of Random Walk, 2nd ed. p. 167). So I tried to use the bold estimate $\mathbb{P}(\sigma_0\leq n|S_0=x)=0$ for $n<|x|_1=|x_1|+|x_2|$ (there are not enough jumps to hit 0) and $\mathbb{P}(\sigma_0\leq n|S_0=x)\leq 1$ else, such that
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_0\leq \beta^{-1}\log(\beta^{-1})T|Z_0=x_\beta)=\sum_{n=|x_\beta|+1}^\infty{\frac{(\beta^{-1}\log(\beta^{-1})T)^n}{n!}e^{-\beta^{-1}\log(\beta^{-1})T}}$$
But this converges to 1, so my bold approach is not sufficient.
Question 2: Is there a better upper bound for $\mathbb{P}(\sigma_0\leq n|S_0=x)$?
Any help or comment is greatly appreciated!
